# Vuetify - Multiple instances of Vue detected

Tags: web-component, vuetify.js, multiple-instances, vue-cli-3, unpkg

I'm using **vue-cli-3.4.1**. After creating project, i'have added **vuetify** to my project using command `vue add vuetify`.
There is another vue web-component, which i'm trying to use in my application.
I have added scripts to **index.html** file, like this

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="path/my-component.min.js"></script>
```

But, after running command `npm run serve`, getting this error in console and showing blank page.

**[Vuetify] Multiple instances of Vue detected**

Answer (score 0):

Your index.html file should only have one vue instance.

The vue-cli structures your application using a module system.

If you don't have one already create a `components` directory and place your `my-component.vue` there.

Then you’ll need to import `my-component.vue`, before you locally register it in the component you want to use it in.

Assuming the below component is named App.vue

```
<template>
  <MyComponent />
</template>

<script>
import MyComponent from './components/my-component'

export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent
  },
  // ...
}
</script>
```

Now `MyComponent` can be used inside App.vue's template.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Hope this helps.